# Jquery : Drag two elements in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag

I'm searching a way to drag two elements by dragging only one.
What I mean, is that I have to drag one element, and another will be drag too without selecting it.
Is that possible ?
Thanks and sorry for my english if it's bad.

Comment: Do you want both elements to be draggable? like drag one or the other and then have both move?

Comment: You should show us what you have tried before we can help you.

Comment: maybe try handling the event `drag` (which can be set using the option `drag`) in `draggable`.

Comment: Please post [**your code**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) you are currently having issues with so we can have a look and see why it is not working. In addition, adding a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar if possible for your specific language) that demonstrates the issue can be very helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, yes, it is possible.
You can use the custom

```
drag();
```

method [there](http://threedubmedia.com/inc/js/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js).

Example :

```
$(.class).drag().drag();
```

as it is chainable.

Take a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ubEqb/58/

Hope it helps.

Comment: not sure about the use of `.drag()`, but looks like we need some plug-in here, you should mention about it.

Comment: I don't think it's jQuery UI, as far as I know jQuery UI has the only 1 thing called `draggable` to handle with dragging. Here is another copy of your demo except that I just add jQuery UI (and jQuery) http://jsfiddle.net/2b7VZ/ but it does not work. In fact the plugin in your demo is called ***jquery.event.drag***. The naming convention used here can make ours confused if it's a separate part of jQuery or just a normal plugin.